# How to get row data of a html table in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$("#tblTest td:nth-child(3) a").click(function (event) {                     
       event.preventDefault();
       var $td = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
       document.getElementById('id').value = $td.eq(0).text();
       document.getElementById('AppName').value = $td.eq(1).text();                        
});
```

I Use this ans and it is working fine but my problem is that  in that td i have 2 buttons(Edit and Delete) on click of edit the function working. But my delete button is not Deleting data bcz  buttonclk event is not working bcz of this  function. plz suggest some ans..

Comment: Please make the effort to write complete words when you ask strangers for help.

Comment: can you share the table structure also

Comment: How have you ascertained that your other handler isn't firing because of this handler? Are there any errors?

Comment: No i  am not getting any error. the click event is not working..On click of delete button i have to call one node function to delete the record

Comment: @Reason: Your code is working now for delete but on click of edit button my table td data is not binding to textbox. if i remove that class  then edit is working but delete is not working... plz suggest something

Comment: Did you add the class to the html? <a ...class="edit_button">? Could you please post the HTML as well, because it's hard to find the error without seeing it.

Comment: @Reason: This is my html--<td class="center">
                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="return OnClickVisible();"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i> Edit</a>
                                                 <a href="DeleteAppRecord/{{this._id}}" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you want to remove this item?')"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete</a>
                                                </td>--- i put this class what i used.. but it is not working.

Comment: @Reason: thanks yar.. You code is working fine. only problem is in my class name..

Comment: Ok, in that case you need to add the edit_button class to your a-element: like this <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning edit_button" onclick="return OnClickVisible();">

Comment: @Reason: ya it is working fine... thanks a lot....

Comment: @Reason: Hi I want to insert data from C# to Mongodb. if you have any idea please  share.. i am new in this...

Comment: @kumar I have no experience in doing that, but it's an entirely different question, so you should search for it on stackoverflow and post a question unless you find the answer. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to answer if you had posted your html, but I'm guessing it looks something like this:

```
<table id="tblTest">
...
<td> <!-- this is the third td in #tblTest (#tblTest td:nth-child(3)) -->
    <a ...>Edit</a>
    <a ...>Delete</a>
</td>
</table>
```

Your jQuery selector is looking for all -tags in the third element. The function then calls event.preventDefault(). The problem is that you match both buttons when all you want is to match the edit button. An easy solution would be to add a class to the edit button and then add that class to the selector, so the function is only triggered for the edit button. This is how i would solve it:

```
<table id="tblTest">
...
<td>
    <a ... class="edit_button">Edit</a> <!-- add class to edit button. -->
    <a ...>Delete</a>
</td>
</table>

// will now only trigger for the edit button.
$("#tblTest td:nth-child(3) a.edit_button").click(function (event) { 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -4):

The jquery selector "$()" only select the first matched element, use ".find(*)" function instead.